# R: Remove Legend Title and Use Custom Color in Mixed Type Plot

Tags: r, colors, plot, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to produce a plot that has scatter-plot type point and a curve being plotted on top of that scatter plot. I am trying to produce a legend that only label the plotted curve as "Power Curve." I can't manage to do this without having a legend title. I would also like to be able to set the colors for the points and the curve. I have tried the below code to get rid of the title without any luck. I hope this makes sense, pretty new to R. Sorry if the formatting is incorrect too.

```
p1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=wind.supply, aes(x=avgWindSpeed, y= kwh), shape=1, color="dodgerblue2", size=1)+
  geom_line(data=powercurve, aes(x=windspeed_mps, y= ten.min.kwh, color="Power Curve"))+
  labs(x="Average Wind Speed",y="Energy Supplied (kWh)") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 20))

p1 + theme(legend.position = c(0.85,0.2), legend.title=NULL)
```

Here is the plot the above code produces, if that helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRiX7.jpg

Here is wind.supply.

```
    datetime        avgWindSpeed  kwh
1 2013-01-01 00:10:00     12.0    550
2 2013-01-01 00:20:00     11.6    550
3 2013-01-01 00:30:00     11.8    549
4 2013-01-01 00:40:00     11.2    551
5 2013-01-01 00:50:00     11.1    550
6 2013-01-01 01:00:00     12.0    550
7 2013-01-01 01:10:00     11.3    550
8 2013-01-01 01:20:00     11.9    550
9 2013-01-01 01:30:00     11.2    550
```

Here is power.curve

```
windspeed_mps   power_kW    ten.min.kwh
85  3.755136    21.7000     25.316667
86  3.799840    23.2500     27.125000
87  3.844544    24.8000     28.933333
88  3.889248    26.3500     30.741667
89  3.933952    27.9000     32.550000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

1. `labs(colour=NULL)` and that will remove the legend title for colour
2. `theme(legend.title = element_blank())`

`labs`  will give you more control as you an specify the aesthetic you are not going to have a legend title for, whereas `theme(legend.title = ...)` dictates the behaviour for all legends

---

```
p1 + theme(legend.position = c(0.85,0.2), legend.title=element_blank())
# or perhaps better
p1 + theme(legend.position = c(0.85,0.2)) + labs(colour=NULL)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Is there a way I can have a different color on powercurve, but still retain the legend label "Power Curve"? Thanks for the help!

Comment: And is there any way to make the legend background transparent?

Comment: `theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill='transparent')` or `theme(legend.background = element_blank())`. You may also want do the same with `legend.key` (see `?theme`) for more details.